# SplitQuery in EF - what is the recommendation based on?

Tags: entity-framework

Does anyone know what EF is basing the analysis on? Just the number of JOINs and maybe the number of columns in the tables used? Does it actually use real data from the database?

My point is, that to be able to know if I should use SingleQuery or SplitQuery, do I not need to run both with a populated database and measure the performance over time?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#enabling-split-queries-globally) says: _EF Core detects that the query loads multiple collections._ Too vague.

Comment: I've been spending a day testing my application with SplitQuery vs. SplitSingle.
In my case, I did not gain anything with SplitQuery. 
(My data model is very complex, highly normalized and many JOINs with few rows in the SELECT.)

So my conclusion is to use the warnings from EF as potential improvements, 
but not use SplitQuery by default. You need to test your queries with your data.

Comment: Ooops, I meant SplitQuery vs. SingleQuery